# How do I create a dictionary/map in Swift with dates as keys and booleans as values?

Tags: java, ios, swift, dictionary, maps

Using swift I want to make a map, using dates as keys and booleans as values. In java I would do the following:

```
private  Map<Date,Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();

private void add() {
    long today = 9999999l;
    map.put(new Date(today), Boolean.TRUE);
    Boolean result = map.get(new Date(today));
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().add();
}
```

In swift I have the following:

```
private var statusOfCells = [NSDate: Bool]()

if let domain = statusOfCells[cell.currentDate] as Bool? {
if (domain){
 doSomething()
 }
}
```

Which results in a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I can't seem to get my head around the optional unwrapping. How would I do it in swift?

Comment: How are you setting values in your dictionary?

Comment: There must be something else, your code runs perfectly without an error, are you doing something else?

Answer (score 1):

Sample swift map usage:

```
let date = NSDate()
var dict = [NSDate: Bool]()
// Set flag
dict[date] = true
// Check
if let flag = dict[date] where flag == true {
    print("flag is true")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data:

```
var statusOfCells: [NSDate: Bool] = [:]
```

Append to the dictionary:

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
statusOfCells[currentDate] = true
```

If you want to check the value of your dictionary and act upon it:

```
if statusOfCells[cell.currentDate] ?? false {
    // Do something
}
```

It's similar to the answer of avdyushin but a bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

If cell.currentDate is null, which in my case it was, the exception gets thrown.

Comment: Well, perhaps next time would be a better idea to show where the error occurs and give us full data about what you're showing. ;)